# Is the Python map function a value-returning function?

Tags: python, list, return-type

I've been trying to work with the `map` function in Python, and I've been having a little bit of trouble with it. I can't tell which of these is the proper way to map function foo to the list bar:

```
map(foo, bar)
```

or

```
newBar = map(foo, bar)
```

I'm getting varied results from different websites. Which of these is the correct usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) returns a list of return values of `foo(...)`. If you don't care about the results and just want to run the elements of `bar` through `foo`, either of your examples will work.

In Python 3, [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator that is evaluated lazily. Neither of your examples will actually run any elements of `bar` through `foo` *yet*. You will need to iterate over that iterator. The simplest way would be to convert it to a list:

```
list(map(foo, bar))
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns a new list, and does not change the one you enter into the function. So, the usage is:

```
def foo(x): #sample function
    return x * 2

bar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newBar = map(foo, bar)
```

In the interpreter:

```
>>> print bar
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print newBar
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

*Note: This is python 2.x*

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 `map()` returns a new list. In Python 3 it returns an iterator. You can convert it into a list with:

```
new_list = list(map(foo, bar))
```

As the name suggests, a common use of an iterator is to iterate over it:

```
for x in map(foo, bar):
    # do something with x
```

This produces one value at a time without putting all values in memory as creating a list would.

Furthermore, you can do single steps through an iterator:

```
my_iter = map(foo, bar)
first_value = next(my_iter)
second_value = next(my_iter)
```

Now work with the rest:

```
for x in map(foo, bar):
    # x starts from the third value
```

This is very common in Python 3. `zip` and `enumerate` also return iterators. Often this is called lazy evaluation, because values are only produce when really need.